# Why does System.out.print() won't print unless I input first?

Tags: java

I wanted the input to be in the same line as the question that's why I used system.out.print() but it wont print unless the age(input) is typed

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("How old are you? ");
int age = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
if (age >= 0 && age <= 120) {
    System.out.println("OK");
} else {
    System.out.println("Impossible!");
}
```

[image: This is the output of the code]

Comment: When I run it I get `How old are you? 130
Impossible!`. How are you running your program?

Comment: I suspect that there's some buffering happening in whatever you use to display your output (likely the IDE).

Comment: I just started learning java yesterday, and I'm following the course by mooc.fi. I'm using tmcbeans/ Netbeans they provided in their website

Comment: could you provide us with the whole code ? like how does the main method looks like and where did you put it

Comment: `import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckingTheAge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        System.out.print("How old are you? ");
        int age = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        if (age >= 0 && age <= 120) {
            System.out.println("OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Impossible!");
        
        }
    }
}` @Helix112

Comment: System.out.flush() wont work either, thanks anyway @RenéLink

Comment: @helpme There must be an issue with your ide. try running the file manually on the command line and see what happens : 
inside the directory where your file is located : 
`javac filenamehere.java` 
then `java filenamehere`

Comment: `System.out.flush();` should work.

Comment: @Helix112 it worked fine on cmd, thank you!

Comment: @helpme Good for you, But that does not solve your issue, the question is rather why do you get such behaviour when runnning your program in netbeans ? maybe try invalidate your IDE cache or something?

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html), that buffers characters, before flushing them to the underlying stream. In this case that underlying stream is your operating systems standard output.

Generally, a flush happens if the internal buffer is full, an array of data has been written or *on a newline* - behaviour is somewhat configurable.

To be sure, you can force a flush by using the `flush()` method.